# Use adb to find folders and files

Tags: windows, cmd, adb

I have researched on the internet and to navigate on my Android using Windows CMD, you need to have ADB installed, once installed you need to open a session in Shell.

But if I needed to search for specific folders and files or make a Dir and show me folders on my drive as well as Windows.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

There are similar commands to do what you're looking for, for instance:

`adb shell` to connect to an emulator (or real device)

`ls`, `ls -l`, etc to list directories and files on specific folders

`mkdir` to create new directory

`find` command to search for files in directory, for instance to look for png files in the current directory you can use `find . -name "*.png"`

There are a lot of other commands available that you can use. Please take a look at tutorials on internet on this topic.